# I used JS to generate a table where every cell has an ID so that I can call upon every cell, but how do I enter and delete stuff in the table?

Tags: javascript

I wrote code to automatically generate a table where every cell has an ID so that I can call upon every individual cell. The actual task is to generate such a table so that I can put text in each cell and have a button to colour the ones that have been filled, give each cell a random colour or remove certain items from said table.

This is what I already wrote, my question is where do I go from here?

```js
function GenerateTable() {
  var table = "";
  var hours = 23;
  var days = 7;
  for (i = 0; i < hours; i++) {
    table += "<tr style='border: 1px solid black;'>";

    for (k = 0; k < days; k++) {
      var ID = i + k * 100;
      table += "<td style='border: 1px solid black;width:50px' id=" + ID + ">" + "..." + "</td>";
    }

    table += "</tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("Agenda").innerHTML = ("<table style='border: 1;border-collapse: collapse;'>" + table + '</table>');
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="GenerateTable()">Genereer Tabel</button>
<table id="Agenda" style='border: 1px solid black;width: 100%;'></table>
```

What I tried to do didn't work and it became more and more of a clusterf***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once had an assignment where we had to make something similar but I'm from the Netherlands so my vars are in dutch. I tweaked it a bit and made some adjustments as to fit your needs. I hope It's enough for you to figure it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        function generatie()
        {
            var table ="";
            var uren = 24;
            var dagen = 7;
            for (var r = 0; r<uren;r++){
                table +="<tr style='border: 1px solid black;'>";
                    for(var c=0;c<dagen;c++){
                        var idtje = r+c*100;
                        table+="<td style='border: 1px solid black;width:50px' id="+idtje+">" +"..."+"</td>";
                    }
                table+="</tr>";
            }
            document.getElementById("Agenda").innerHTML=("<table style='border: 1;border-collapse: collapse;'>"+table+'</table>');
        }

        function PlaatsEvent()
        {
            var Dag = document.getElementById("Dag").value-1;
            console.log(Dag);
            var Start = document.getElementById("Startuur").value;
            console.log(Start);
            var Duur = document.getElementById("Duratie").value;
            console.log(Duur);
            var totID = Number((Dag*100))+Number(Start);
            console.log(totID);
            var i = 0;
            var bezet = "yeet";
            while(i!=Duur){
                var volId = Number(totID)+Number(i);
                console.log(volId);
                document.getElementById(volId).innerText=bezet;
                i++;
            }
        }
            /////var k = Number(i) + Number(j);

        function gevuld()
        {
            var dagTeller = 0;
            var urenTeller = 0;
            while(dagTeller!=700)
            {
                while(urenTeller!=23)
                {
                    var totID = Number(dagTeller)+Number(urenTeller);
                    if(document.getElementById(totID).innerText!="...")
                    {
                        document.getElementById(totID).style.backgroundColor='#003F87';
                    }
                    urenTeller++;
                }
                urenTeller = 0;
                dagTeller = Number(dagTeller)+Number(100);
            }
        }

        function random()
        {
            var dagTeller = 0;
            var urenTeller = 0;
            while(dagTeller!=700)
            {
                while(urenTeller!=23)
                {
                    var totID = Number(dagTeller)+Number(urenTeller);
                    var Color = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
                    document.getElementById(totID).style.backgroundColor=("#"+Color);
                    urenTeller++;
                }
                urenTeller = 0;
                dagTeller = Number(dagTeller)+Number(100);
            }
        }
        function Verwijderen()
        {
            var dagTeller = 0;
            var urenTeller = 0;
            var teVerwijderen = document.getElementById("Verwijderen").value;
            while(dagTeller!=700)
            {
                while(urenTeller!=23)
                {
                    var totID = Number(dagTeller)+Number(urenTeller);
                    
                    if(document.getElementById(totID).innerText==teVerwijderen)
                    {
                        document.getElementById(totID).innerText="...";
                    }
                    urenTeller++;
                }
                urenTeller = 0;
                dagTeller = Number(dagTeller)+Number(100);
            }
        }
        
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Klik op de knop om uw agenda te genereren.</p>
    <button type="submit" onclick=generatie()>Generate</button> <br>
    <table id="Agenda" style='border: 1px solid black;width: 100%;'></table>
    <p>kies een dag (1-7), startuur (0-23) en geef aan hoe lang de activiteit zal duren (in uur)</p>
    <input type="text" id="Dag"><input type="text" id="Startuur"><input type="text" id="Duratie"><button type="submit" onclick=PlaatsEvent()>Submit</button>

    <input type="text" id="Verwijderen">wat wilt u verwijderen? (geef het onderwerp)</input><button type="submit" onclick=Verwijderen()>verwijderen?</button>

    <button type="submit" onclick=gevuld()>Gevulde momenten</button>

    <button type="submit" onclick=random()>Geef random kleur</button>
</body>
</html>
```